# How do you pass an object in jQuery when another object is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html code like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCopyright" placeholder="IN" />

<div class="input-group-btn nopadding">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  style="border-radius:0"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="myDropdown" role="menu">
    <li><a>IN</a></li>
    <li><a>BEFORE</a></li>
    <li><a>AFTER</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Other input-group

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtOtherInput" placeholder="Other" />

<div class="input-group-btn nopadding">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  style="border-radius:0"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="myDropdown2" role="menu">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and i have a jQuery like this..

```
$('#myDropdown li').click(function () {
    $('#txtCopyright').val($(this).text());
});

$('#myDropdown2 li').click(function () {
   $('#txtOtherInput').val($(this).text());
});
```

It actually work in me.. but the problem is that i want to use only one jQuery in all my dropdown.. it is easy to use for now because i have only 2 dropdown what if i have 20 dropdown then i will set 20 jQuery's and I think it is redundant..

My idea is to pass the id of inputs but how to do that..

Any idea..

Please help me
Thank you.

Comment: You could bind them with data attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If all dropdown/ input pairings each are contained in a single parent wrapper the whole issue is fairly easy. Give the input's a common class. Then from the dropdown it is a simple traverse to main parent and look for input inside by class

```
<div class="module_wrap">
    <input class="menu-input" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCopyright" placeholder="IN" />
    <div class="input-group-btn nopadding">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-radius:0"><span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="myDropdown" role="menu">
            <li><a>IN</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>BEFORE</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>AFTER</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.module_wrap').find('.menu-input').val($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: It's important to not bind dropdown with id or problem still persist.

Comment: @mdesdev why is that?....the id comes from markup and this code covers all in dropdown. The relationship has to be established somewhere and this is as good a way as any other. It also answers OP's question

Comment: Ok but what to do on 20+ dropdowns with same id ;)

Comment: I see you got the error on second answer :) I retracted the vote, never mind...yes of course ID must be unique, OP asked what if he have 20+ dropdowns, he doesn't want to write the code 20 times. Anyhow just call element with the class and that's it ;)

Comment: @mdesdev my bad...is late, was thinking about the other ID

Comment: @user3792802 it is...there are likely easier approaches but you need to confirm wrappers for the inputs that this will get set to. If each `module` is wrapped it greatly simplifies a lot. Then traverse to wrapper and look for class assigned to the input's

Comment: I know, I'm tired too it's 5:13AM...but it's maybe better to set `data-input` to `ul` ;) Then target it with parent/closest of course.

Comment: Ok because we're both tired I'm giving you +1 ;)

Comment: completely revised answer with outer wrapper and much simpler code

Comment: i tried it but still @charlietfl's answer is better than what i did.. but if there's a way without using `data-input` then i will grab it.. but for now it is the best way.. i just use `class` instead of `id`... thanks a lot men..

Comment: That's the right way, my first thinking was about this but people don't like to change their HTML, don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Apply class selector and use data- attribute:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="myDropdown" data-control-id="txtCopyright" role="menu">
    <li><a>IN</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>BEFORE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>AFTER</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and on click of **li** use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get parent **ul** and then fetch its `data-control-id` attribute value and then do like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
    $('#'+$(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").data("control-id")).val($(this).text());
});
```

or:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
        $('#'+$(this).parent(".dropdown-menu").data("control-id")).val($(this).text());
    });
```

### DEMO:

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/W9gy6/)

Comment: wrong element, you have no data attributes on `<li>`